# Provider test integration with pact broker for Spring Boot junit5 + configuration in application properties

Tags: pact, pact-broker

The pact-jvm-provider-spring states that for junit5 provider test, it is not required to use the spring library.

However, @PactBroker annotation depends on the system properties. Is there a way to get this working for application properties via the Spring Property Resolver. I tried to create something similar to SpringEnvironmentResolver.kt and used it in the context setup. But that did not work.

```
@Provider("api-provider-app")
@PactBroker
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class PactVerificationTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
    void testTemplate(Pact pact, Interaction interaction, HttpRequest request,
                  PactVerificationContext context) {
        context.setTarget(new HttpTestTarget("localhost", port));
        context.setValueResolver(new SpringResolver(environment));
        context.verifyInteraction();
    }
}
```

I get the following **error**

> Invalid pact broker host specified ('${pactbroker.host:}'). Please provide a valid host or specify the system property 'pactbroker.host'.

**Update**
After some more searching found out that the setTarget was not working and that needs to be moved to @BeforeEach method.

```
@BeforeEach
void setContext(PactVerificationContext context) {
    context.setValueResolver(new SpringResolver(environment));
    context.setTarget(new HttpTestTarget("localhost", port));
}
```

The following snippet helped it work with @PactFolder annotation. But the @PactBroker with properties is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new module added to Pact-JVM that extends the JUnit5 support to allow values to be configured in the Spring Context. See https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/provider/pact-jvm-provider-junit5-spring. It will be released with the next version of Pact-JVM, which will be 4.0.7.

Comment: Thank you Ronald. This is of great help. Looking forward to the next release version.

Comment: Hi Ronald, any estimate when will the 4.0.7 will be released.

Comment: Tested with 4.0.8 and it is working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm using pact-jvm-provider-junit5 and I can't use configuration in application properties. I got this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve property "pactbroker.host" in the system properties or environment variables and no default value is supplied

Comment: this link is broken for me, 404 on github.

Comment: Updated link:
https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/tree/master/provider/spring6